# do java compiler or JIT optimize no-parameter static method

Tags: java, static-methods, jit

I'm not savvy on java compiler but wondering if java does such optimization. here's the problem:

```
class A {

private final static Map<String, String> fruitIds = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {

        fruitIds.put("Orange", "1");
        fruitIds.put("Apple", "2");
        fruitIds.put("banana", "4");    
}
    public static Set<Integer> getSortedFruitSet() {
        Iterator<String> iterator = fruitIds.values().iterator();
        Set<Integer> returnSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            returnSet.add(Integer.valueOf(iterator.next()));
        }
        return returnSet;
    }
}
```

I know I can use Enums here but even with that I may have same issue. Every time I call `getSortedFruitSet` it probably creates new TreeSet and populates it which seems unnecessary. I can create another static instance of this TreeSet but is there another way to optimize this? Do compiler or runtime make any optimization for such static method? Does it even make sense to optimize such method calls?

Comment: I would say there is something deeply wrong with your data design here. You seem to be crying out for an Enum.

Comment: If you return an unmodifiable set (see **Collections.unmodifableSet**) for that actually unmodifiableMap, then a marginally clever compiler could have done that. In C it would be likely, in Java much is left to the JIT.

Comment: @EJP I thought of that as well when I first looked at this legacy code. however I think it doesnt solve the problem

Comment: I am suggesting to you that it is the problem itself that is wrong. If the fruit is known ahead of time, so are its ID values, so constructing a new Set of thise on demand every time is futile. The answer to the problem posed is `{1,2,4}`, from here to eternity. Writing a method to return that at all suggests a data design problem. Why do you need the ID at all? Surely `EnumMap` or `EnumSet` solves this problem completely?

Comment: I need IDs. EnumMap seems interesting. It looks like it maintains natural order of enum (in order they been defined).  and seem compact in storage and hence efficient than regular map. thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

### The java compiler does no such optimization

When we look at your getSortedFruitSet() method with  `javap -c` we can see the compiled version of this code.

```
    public static java.util.Set<java.lang.Integer> getSortedFruitSet();
descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Set;
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=2, args_size=0
     0: getstatic     #2                  // Field fruitIds:Ljava/util/Map;
     3: invokeinterface #3,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.values:()Ljava/util/Collection;
     8: invokeinterface #4,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Collection.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
    13: astore_0
    14: new           #5                  // class java/util/TreeSet
    17: dup
    18: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/util/TreeSet."<init>":()V
    21: astore_1
    22: aload_0
    23: invokeinterface #7,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
    28: ifeq          53
    31: aload_1
    32: aload_0
    33: invokeinterface #8,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
    38: checkcast     #9                  // class java/lang/String
    41: invokestatic  #10                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    44: invokeinterface #11,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/Set.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    49: pop
    50: goto          22
    53: aload_1
    54: areturn
  LineNumberTable:
    line 13: 0
    line 14: 14
    line 15: 22
    line 16: 31
    line 18: 53
  StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
    frame_type = 253 /* append */
      offset_delta = 22
      locals = [ class java/util/Iterator, class java/util/Set ]
    frame_type = 30 /* same */
Signature: #36
```

So as youcan see, there is always a `new`and `invokespecial`associated to the TreeSet. (This creates a new Object of TreeSet, the creation becomes two steps when you look at the bytecode. One step `new` and one `invokespecial` which calls the constructor.

### The JIT compiler can (possibly) do this

The JIT can possible do optimization here, but it does this on methods that are frequently executed. To test this, you would need to call the method a lot of times and see what assembly code the JIT generates. **I can not verify this right now** but might get back to the answer and so later - if no one else has done so in the meantime.

---

Sorry for only answering part of your question. The Java compiler (from java to bytecode) does in general only very little optimization by the way :-)